# Fast forward minecraft client (forge mod)

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I want to create a way (like with a forge mod) to speed-up the minecraft client (as in the whole game). It takes the game 20 minutes to pass from day to night, and lets say that theres an "advance" button in the GUI (in terms of a forge mod). I'm trying to change speed so that if the "advance" button is pressed, for example, there is only 5 minutes between day and night and it doubles the speed of the player, so that everything looks like it's being fast forwarded like on a dvd.

I've made research and it seems the only way  to do something like this is by modding the game or with a plugin or something.

P.S. I'm running Minecraft on Linux.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too broad and not really about programming.

Comment: Well if you have a way too access minecraft code, it is about programming. If you know it is possible to do it with mods creation tools, it is about programming too. If you know how to speed up process in linux, it's not programming but still informatic.

Comment: @user2329273 - do you know Java?

Comment: Maybe this somewhat helpful http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52441/is-there-a-way-to-see-minecrafts-source-code

Comment: *Jeremy Barnes: I know java quite well  
*Timgeb: Thank you I will look at MCP

Comment: Why is this question still marked as closed? I edited it to isolate a problem and made it more specific.

Comment: And I ask for moderator intervention a while ago, I don't know why it is still close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the speed of the time and moving forward have to be done separately.

## Speed of Day (Tick Rate)

The speed of the day is based on the amount of `ticks`, which is one big loop that controls the time. `ticks` also control everything in the game. When the amount of ticks increases or resets, various aspects of the game move forward a little bit including mobs, objects, and the players stats. According to [Minecraft Wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tick#Game_tick), Minecraft runs at a fixed 20 t/s (ticks per second), which also means 1 t/0.05 seconds; an in-game day lasts exactly 24000 ticks, or 20 minutes in real time. Since this loop is directly programmed into Minecraft's code, changing the tick rate can really mess up the game. If you make the tick rate too fast when your computer can't handle it, you'll get the classic `[Server thread/WARN]: Can't keep up! Did the system time change, or is the server overloaded? Running Xms behind, skipping Y tick(s)` and then possible a crash, since the system time actually DID change (for once), so be careful about speeding up the game too hard.

Something like this would work (retreived and edited from [here](https://github.com/Guichaguri/TickrateChanger/blob/1.8.9/src/main/java/me/guichaguri/tickratechanger/TickrateChanger.java)):

```
public class ChangeTickRate implements IFMLLoadingPlugin, IFMLCallHook {
    // Stored client-side tickrate (default at 20TPS)
    private Field clientTimer = null;
    @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
    public static void updateClientTickrate(float tickrate) {
        Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();
        if(mc == null) return; // Oops! Try again!
        try {
            if(clientTimer == null) {
                for(Field f : mc.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                    if(f.getType() == Timer.class) {
                        clientTimer = f;
                        clientTimer.setAccessible(true);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            clientTimer.set(mc, new Timer(tickrate));
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to include all the imports. Comment if you run into any errors before or while running it.
***NOTE:*** This only changes the **client** side tick rate, so it would cause problems on a server without the proper methods.

## Player Movement

Since player movement is slightly based on ticks, and you already changing the TPS, it may be better just to give them an infinite potion of swiftness:

```
int PotionAmp = 1; //base amplifier of the effect
while(FastForwardEnabled){
    player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(Potion.moveSpeed.id, 0, 1));  
}
```

this hides the bubbles effect and uses the standard effect level, or amplifier. If you want more control over player speed, then try something like this instead (probably as an override):

```
//play around with this number
private static final float FFSpeed = 0.2f
@Override //probably
public boolean onTickInGame(float f, Minecraft minecraft){
    minecraft.thePlayer.speedOnGround=0.02f;
    return true; //tell it that this is handled
}
```

## Conclusion

Now, after you have created your own GUI class and button, all you have to do is call it like this in your GUI class

```
//see https://bedrockminer.jimdo.com/modding-tutorials/advanced-modding/gui-screen/ for some reference
private static boolean FastForwardEnabled = false;
protected void actionPerformed(GuiButton button) throws IOException {
    if (button == AdvanceButton) { //Example GUI Button used as an enable/disable
        FastForwardEnabled = !FastForwardEnabled;
        while (FastForwardEnabled){
            //Example value used; increases game speed 2x
            ChangeTickRate.updateClientTickrate(40);
            player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(Potion.moveSpeed.id, 0, 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very clear and concise explanation. +1